# Definitive way to parse alphanumeric CSVs in Python with scipy/numpy

Tags: python, parsing, csv, numpy, scipy

I've been trying to find a good and flexible way to parse CSV files in Python but none of the standard options seem to fit the bill.  I am tempted to write my own but I think that some combination of what exists in numpy/scipy and the csv module can do what I need, and so I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I'd like the standard features of being able to specify delimiters, specify whether or not there's a header, how many rows to skip, comments delimiter, which columns to ignore, etc.  The central feature I am missing is being able to parse CSV files in a way that gracefully handles both string data and numeric data.  Many of my CSV files have columns that contain strings (not of the same length necessarily) and numeric data.  I'd like to be able to have numpy array functionality for this numeric data, but also be able to access the strings.  For example, suppose my file looks like this (imagine columns are tab-separated):

```
# my file
name  favorite_integer  favorite_float1  favorite_float2  short_description
johnny  5  60.2  0.52  johnny likes fruitflies
bob 1  17.52  0.001  bob, bobby, robert

data = loadcsv('myfile.csv', delimiter='\t', parse_header=True, comment='#')
```

I'd like to be able to access data in two ways:

1. As a matrix of values: it's important for me to get a numpy.array so that I can easily transpose and access the columns that are numeric.  In this case, I want to be able to do something like:

   `floats_and_ints = data.matrix`

   `floats_and_ints[:, 0] # access the integers`

   `floats_and_ints[:, 1:3] # access some of the floats`
   `transpose(floats_and_ints)  # etc..`
2. As a dictionary-like object where I don't have to know the order of the headers: I'd like to also access the data by the header order.  For example, I'd like to do:

   `data['favorite_float1'] # get all the values of the column with header
                             "favorite_float1"`

   `data['name'] # get all the names of the rows`

I don't want to have to know that favorite_float1 is the second column in the table, since this might change.

It's also important for me to be able to iterate through the rows and access the fields by name. For example:

```
for row in data:
  # print names and favorite integers of all 
  print "Name: ", row["name"], row["favorite_int"]
```

The representation in (1) suggest a numpy.array, but as far as I can tell, this does not deal well with strings and requires me to specify the data type ahead of time as well as the header labels.

The representation in (2) suggests a list of dictionaries, and this is what I have been using. However, this is really bad for csv files that have two string fields but the rest of the columns are numeric.  For the numeric values, you really do want to be able to sometime get access to the matrix representation and manipulate it as a numpy.array.

Is there a combination of csv/numpy/scipy features that allows the flexibility of both worlds?  Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

In summary, the main features are:

1. Standard ability to specify delimiters, number of rows to skip, columns to ignore, etc.
2. The ability to get a numpy.array/matrix representation of the data so that it can numeric values can be manipulated
3. The ability to extract columns and rows by header name (as in the above example)

Comment: Uh, you know, that doesn't look much like CSV to me...

Comment: Everything written above applies to any CSV/TSV file. The differences are in how the CSV/TSV is represented -- both kinds of representations (list of dicts, indexed by header) and matrix representations for easy manipulations of numeric fields are useful and I'd like a framework that easily allows me to do both.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is build on top of `numpy`.
Here is a small example:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', index_col='name')
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
        favorite_integer  favorite_float1  favorite_float2        short_description
name                                                                               
johnny                 5            60.20            0.520  johnny likes fruitflies
bob                    1            17.52            0.001       bob, bobby, robert
In [9]: df.describe()
Out[9]: 
       favorite_integer  favorite_float1  favorite_float2
count          2.000000         2.000000         2.000000
mean           3.000000        38.860000         0.260500
std            2.828427        30.179317         0.366988
min            1.000000        17.520000         0.001000
25%            2.000000        28.190000         0.130750
50%            3.000000        38.860000         0.260500
75%            4.000000        49.530000         0.390250
max            5.000000        60.200000         0.520000
In [13]: df.ix['johnny', 'favorite_integer']
Out[13]: 5
In [15]: df['favorite_float1'] # or attribute: df.favorite_float1
Out[15]: 
name
johnny    60.20
bob       17.52
Name: favorite_float1
In [16]: df['mean_favorite'] = df.mean(axis=1)
In [17]: df.ix[:, 3:]
Out[17]: 
              short_description  mean_favorite
name                                          
johnny  johnny likes fruitflies      21.906667
bob          bob, bobby, robert       6.173667
```

Answer (score 2):

[`matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) returns a `numpy` [`recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), so you can do all the great `numpy` things to this that you would do with any `numpy` array.  The individual rows, being [`record`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.record.html) instances, can be indexed as tuples but also have attributes automatically named for the columns in your data:

```
rows = matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec('data.csv')
row = rows[0]

print row[0]
print row.name
print row['name']
```

`csv2rec` also understands "quoted strings", unlike `numpy.genfromtext`.

In general, I find that `csv2rec` combines some of the best features of `csv.reader` and `numpy.genfromtext`.

Answer (score 0):

numpy.genfromtxt()

Comment: Please link to the docs whenever possible: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the stdlib csv.DictReader?